# ng-table not updating without page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pusher, ngtable

I've come across some odd behavior with ng-table. When I refresh the page the reload() method works fine, updating the new data as it comes in via a socket events. When I go from one part of the app to the next without a full refresh, the socket event calls the same function that works after refresh but fails to reload the table.

Here is the table:

```
 vm.communicationEventLogsTableParams = new ngTableParams({
     page: 1,            // show first page
     count: 5,
     sorting: {
         createdDate: 'dsc'     // initial sorting
     }
 }, {
    counts: [5,10,25,50],
    total: vm.communicationEventLogs ? vm.communicationEventLogs.length : 0, // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {

    //load data from resource

     CommunicationEventLog.getCommunicationEventLogs({workorderId: $stateParams.workorderId}, function (data) {
        vm.communicationEventLogs = data;
        console.log('hi');

        console.log('GETTING DATA FOR COMM EVENT LOG TABLE');
        var filteredData = vm.communicationEventLogs;
        filteredData = $filter('filter')(filteredData, vm.mySearch);
        if (filteredData) params.total(filteredData.length);

        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
            $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
            filteredData;
        if (orderedData)
            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

        console.log(params);
    });

}
});
```

Here is the function calling the reload, called by a socket event:

```
 realTimeChannelFactory.on(realTimeChannelFactory.events.CELA, function (args) {

     console.log("RT_Event: Communication Log Event!");

     vm.communicationEventLogsTableParams.reload();

 });
```

The data is in the DOM because I can log it to the console when an event is fired. The strangest part is if I filter the table, ng-table does another reload and the data is visible in the table.

Comment: Are you using the [pusher-angular](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-angular) library? The main thing it does is deal with the [digest loop](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-angular/blob/master/lib/pusher-angular.js#L56). The reason I mention this is because the symptom of an update occurring outside of the digest loop is the update value not being reflected in the UI, but being in the model/scope.

Comment: No, we're not using the pusher-angular library... That's probably why a $watch in one of our other controllers populates the table but this one doesn't.